# np.linalg.eig returning incorrect eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my python code with the wrong answer:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[-0.5, 0., 0., 0.],
              [0., -1., -1., 0.],
              [0., -1., -1., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., -1.5]])
print(np.linalg.eig(A))
```

Output:

```py
(array([ 0. , -2. , -0.5, -1.5]), array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))
```

Here is my Mathematica code with the right answer:

```js
In[1]:= mat={{-0.5, 0, 0, 0},{0,-1,-1,0},{0,-1,-1,0},{0,0,0,-1.5}}
Out[1]= {{-0.5,0,0,0},{0,-1,-1,0},{0,-1,-1,0},{0,0,0,-1.5}} 
In[2]:= Eigensystem[mat]
Out[2]= {{-2.,-1.5,-0.5,0.},{{0.,0.707107,0.707107,0.},{0.,0.,0.,1.},{1.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,-0.707107,0.707107,0.}}}
```

What am I missing here? Is Python misinterpreting my matrix?

Comment: Looks like a match to me.

Comment: Are you confused because numpy returns the eigenvectors as columns instead of rows?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result is correct.

The order in which the eigenvalues ​​appear is not important, but the eigenvectors that follow them are.  Note that all eigenvalues ​​match the eigenvectors, since eigenvectors in numpy are given by columns, not rows.

See the docs here: [Numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html)